# Custom default text in a \newcommand argument in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I'm using `\newcommand` for create some custom functions in my text. Some of these functions have 2 or 3 arguments and many times I confuse the input order.

The default commands of LaTeX in my TeXstudio editor shows suggestions like

[image]

[image]

But the new commands does not do it, only shows `arg1` and `arg2`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{#2 and then #1}

\begin{document}

\test{second}{first}

\test{arg1}{arg2}

\textbf{text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

There is a way to change the words `arg1` and `arg2` for `second` and `first` for example?

`\test{second}{first}` instead `\test{arg1}{arg2}`

Comment: I added `texstudio` as a tag, as well.

Comment: Why not redefining the command so that first be in place of `arg1` and `second` to be in place of `arg2`? Also `custom` is not a good tag... Everything in TeX can be consider as custom...

Comment: @koleygr I guess the MWE is over simplified. Something like `\newcommand{\mypic}[3][]{\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\caption{#3}\end{figure}}` and then the syntax explanation `options`, `file`, `caption` instead of `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`, respectively, would be useful.

Comment: May be your example (with first and second) is just an example and you want something like \test{color}{distance}{shape}... Or similar... Please make it clear

Comment: @Skillmon... Thanks... Thought about it just some minutes after commented...